# Python dictionary with lookup that returns an iterator

Tags: python, dictionary, sorteddictionary

Something I miss about C++ std::map (which is a sorted dictionary) is that looking up a key returns an iterator pointing to the correct location in the map. This means you can lookup a key and then start iterating from there, e.g. if the key is actually the beginning of a range you are interested in, or if you wanted "the item in my dictionary just after key".

Is there some other python dict that supports this kind of functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491037/mapping-stdmap-to-python, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: You could dig into the OrderedDict implementation to implement a solution, but the implementation itself is version dependent and there might not always be a way to do this in the future. FWIW, Python 2.7 `foo._OrderedDict__map[somekey][1][2]` and 3.2 `foo._OrderedDict__map[somekey].next.key` will each give you the key following `somekey`, but don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

Python's native OrderedDict class in the collections module doesn't support an operation to advance forward from a key chosen at random.  There are other implementations of ordered dictionaries that do support that operation.  One of these may meet your needs:

- http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/sandbox/raw-file/tip/odict.py
- http://babel.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/babel/util.py?rev=374#L178
- http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/datastructures.py?rev=7140#L53
- http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html
- http://www.xs4all.nl/~anthon/Python/ordereddict/
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/StableDict/0.2
- http://codespeak.net/svn/user/arigo/hack/pyfuse/OrderedDict.py

Comment: Python's native `OrderedDict` class also doesn't keep it contents in key sort order. I think the OP needs to look at implementations of what would be called a `SortedDict`.

Comment: It is trivial to sort data for a given key-function and the insert it into an OrderedDict for lookup and traversal:  http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes  That works fine unless new keys are added, then a resort is required (though SortedDict implementations also have to do an insort() on every insertion or do a lazily do a full sort before a lookup).

Answer (score 2):

In Python2.7+, you could use an OrderedDict:

```
import collections
import itertools

foo=collections.OrderedDict((('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)))
for key,value in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]!='b',foo.iteritems()):
    print(key,value)
```

yields

```
('b', 2)
('c', 3)
```

For Python2.6 or less, you could use the [OrderedDict recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/).

Comment: This way, you end up with O(n) look-up time.

Comment: Iterating over the items in `foo` is O(n) anyway, so I don't think looking up the beginning of the iterator in O(1) time would improve the overall time complexity. (O(1) lookup can be done with `foo._OrderedDict__map`, but that would depend on implementation details.)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

print my_dict

keys = my_dict.keys()
keys.sort()
start_index = keys.index('b')

for key in keys[start_index:]:
    print key, my_dict[key]
```

=================================

{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}

b 2

c 3

d 4

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need O(log n) inserts and deletes at arbitrary positions, you can use a list of key-value pairs, and use [`bisect.bisect()`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) to look up items:

```
d = [("a", 3), ("b", 4), ("c", 5)]
i = bisect.bisect(d, ("b",))
print d[i + 1]
```

prints

```
('c', 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Python sortedcontainers module](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) provides a [SortedDict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) type that supports this in a couple ways.

[SortedDict.irange](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sortedcontainers.SortedDict.d.irange) returns an iterator that slices the mapping's keys:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
values = SortedDict(enumerate(range(10)))
assert list(values.irange(5, 8)) == [5, 6, 7, 8
```

And SortedDicts are also indexable:

```
assert values.iloc[4] == 4
assert values.iloc[2:5] == [2, 3, 4]
assert values.index(7) == 7
```

The `iloc` attribute is a proxy for efficiently slicing or getting items by index. The `index` method works oppositely.

The SortedContainers project [includes benchmarks](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) and extensive testing. Tests cover 100% of the project and stress runs for hours before every major release.