# Python equivalent of std::set and std::multimap

Tags: c++, python, performance, data-structures, dictionary

I'm porting a C++ program to Python. There are some places where it uses `std::set` to store objects that define their own comparison operators. Since the Python standard library has no equivalent of `std::set` (a sorted key-value mapping data structure) I tried using a normal dictionary and then sorting it when iterating, like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    items = self._data.items()
    items.sort()
    return iter(items)
```

However, profiling has shown that all the calls from `.sort()` to `__cmp__` are a serious bottleneck. I need a better data structure - essentially a sorted dictionary. Does anyone know of an existing implementation? Failing that, any recommendations on how I should implement this? Read performance is more important than write performance and time is more important than memory.

Bonus points if it supports multiple values per key, like the C++ `std::multimap`.

Note that the `OrderedDict` class doesn't fit my needs, because it returns items in the order of insertion, whereas I need them sorted using their `__cmp__` methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sorted dictionary, you can (ab)use the stable nature of python's timsort: basically, keep the items partially sorted, append items at the end when needed, switching a "dirty" flag, and sort the remaining before iterating. See this entry for details and implementation (A Martelli's answer):
[Key-ordered dict in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319763/key-ordered-dict-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

You should use `sort(key=...)`.
The key function you use will be related to the cmp you are already using. The advantage is that the key function is called n times whereas the cmp is called nlog n times, and typically key does half the work that cmp does

If you can include your `__cmp__()` we can probably show you how to convert it to a key function

If you are doing lots of iterations between modifications, you should cache the value of the sorted items.

Comment: While not directly answering the question about data structures this has certainly helped to improve performance. +1

Answer (score 4):

Python does not have built-in data-structures for this, though the `bisect` module provides functionality for keeping a sorted list with appropriately efficient algorithms.

If you have a list of sorted keys, you can couple it with a `collections.defaultdict(list)` to provide multimap-like functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In his book "[Programming in Python 3](http://www.qtrac.eu/py3book.html)", Mark Summerfield introduces a sorted dictionary class. The source code is available in [this zip archive](http://www.qtrac.eu/py3book30.zip) - look for SortedDict.py. The SortedDict class is described in detail in the book (which I recommend very much). It supports arbitrary keys for comparison and multiple values per key (which any dictionary in Python does, so that's not that big a deal, I think).

Answer (score 0):

This is a late post but if anyone is looking for this now, here you go: https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/

This is not a built-in but just an easy pip install. It has sorted dicts and lists both with full support for insert, delete, indexing and binary search. Most of the operations have amortised `O(log(n))` complexity.