# Problems while trying to extract all the values from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I have the following nested [dict](https://pastebin.com/R3hMA1gV). How can I extract in a list all the values of key `'_type'`? I tried to:

```
for e in d.values():
    print (e['_type'])
```

However, I am getting a `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. In this cases which should be the correct way of extracting all the possible values that can take `_type`?

Comment: please copy-paste the data in d here, cant access your link

Comment: a dictionary just got one value for a key, what do you mean "list all the values"?

Comment: @AlexandreAragão, that value can be a list also.

Comment: @Austin yes, the value (without 's') can be a list, still one single value, not valueS, that is why I ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting all values of key `_type` into a list (using recursion):

```
def extract_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k=='_type':
                yield v
            else:
                yield from extract_keys(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from extract_keys(v)

out = list(extract_keys(d)) # variable `d` is your dict from your question

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['FunctionDef', 'arguments', 'arg', 'Expr', 'Str', 'Assign', 'Name', 'Store', 'Num', 'For', 'Assign', 'Name', 'Store', 'BinOp', 'BinOp', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'Load', 'BitXor', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load', 'Name', 'Load', 'Add', 'BinOp', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'Load', 'RShift', 'Num', 'Add', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'Load', 'LShift', 'Num', 'BitAnd', 'Num', 'Name', 'Load', 'Name', 'Store', 'Return', 'Name', 'Load']
```

Comment: @anon There are various question here on SO, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860813/recursively-traverse-multidimensional-dictionary-dimension-unknown

Answer (score 1):

you can find any data from nested dictionary using key :

```
def findDataFromNestedDict(nestedDict, dict_keys):
    if dict_keys in nestedDict.keys():
        return nestedDict[dict_keys]
    for key, value in nestedDict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return  findDataFromNestedDict(value,dict_keys)

data =  findDataFromNestedDict(yourDictionary, yourKey)
```

Comment: How can I understand how to traverse recursively this structures?

Comment: read this : https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/an-introduction-to-recursion-part-1/

Answer (score -2):

Supposing that you dic is something like:

```
dic = {'hi':[1,2,3], 'hello': [4,5,6]}
```

And that you want to get 1, 2, 3 from [1,2,3], do this:

```
for e in dic['hi']:
    print(e)
```