# How to only get the nested keys from a JSON structure in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
json_structure = 
{
"a":1,
"b":2,
"c":[
     {
     "d":4,
     "e":5,
     "f":{
         "g":6
         }
     }
    ]
"d":[
     {
      "h": 7,
      "i": 8,
      }
    ]
}
```

I am able to get a, b, c, d no problem using:

```
json_structure.keys()
```

But now I want to get only the `c` nested keys (d, e, f).

Haven't found a way to do this when explicitly stating `c` keys only.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860813/recursively-traverse-multidimensional-dictionary-dimension-unknown

Comment: Just use the key and take the first element of the list? `json_structure['c'][0].keys()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a few utility functions that recursively drill down the structure to access any specific value, keys or items.  This could process lists as if they were dictionaries with the keys being the indices.

```
def deepValue(D,key,*rest,default=None):
    try:    return deepValue(D[key],*rest,default=default) if rest else D[key]
    except: return default

def deepKeys(D,key,*rest):
    try:
        return deepKeys(D[key],*rest) if rest \
          else D[key].keys() if isinstance(D[key],dict) \
          else range(len(D[key]))
    except:
        return []

def deepItems(D,key,*rest):
    try:
        if rest:
            yield from deepItems(D[key],*rest)
        elif isinstance(D[key],dict):
            yield from D[key].items()
        else:
            yield from enumerate(D[key])
    except: return
```

output:

```
for k in deepKeys(json_structure,"c",0):
    print(k)

# d
# e
# f


print(deepValue(json_structure,"c",0))

# {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': {'g': 6}}

print(deepValue(json_structure,"c",0,"d"))

# 4    
    

for k,v in deepItems(json_structure,"c",0):
    print(k,v)

# d 4
# e 5
# f {'g': 6}
```

Comment: This is an cool approach and seemed to work. Only works with lists though. What if I had a dictionary nested in there. For instance: {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": { "d": 3, "e": 5, "f": {"g": 6, "h": 7} } }

Comment: It is designed to work with any combination of nested dictionaries and lists