# Python 2.6 TreeMap/SortedDictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.6, treemap, sorteddictionary

Is there a *built-in* sorted dictionary implementation in Python 2.6, or are hashtables the only kind?

#### Clarifications:

- I'm asking about *sorted* dictionarys, **not** *ordered* dictionaries!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key-ordered dict in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319763/key-ordered-dict-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer here is no.

There is a Treemap but it isn't in the python standard library.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/treemap/

I think to those who don't like my answer, may think it's wrong due to a recent update. Please note this is for Python 2.6, not 2.7 or Python 3

Please add the correct answer if you still think it's wrong, or unhelpful, or at least give a reason why you think it's a bad answer.

Comment: +1 it's funny how Python was supposed to have a really complete set of features, and yet I'm running across so many things it doesn't have built-in (various containers, do-while loops, switch statements, etc.). :(

Comment: Yes the lack of do-while and switch statements were one of the things I wish were present in python, but have gotten used to their absence now, and don't even notice the lack of them any more.

Comment: Not sure on 3+ but 2.7 doesn't have it either. The give advice on how to make one here, but it still isn't there by default: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes

Comment: And the question was if there was a built-in sorted dictionary in Python 2.6 and the answer is no, regardless of whether one exists in Python 2.7 or Python 3+

Comment: The link is actually to a python library that creates the Treemap visualization instead of a Treemap data structure

Comment: Quiet right, but the essential answer I gave is still correct.  Maybe I should have left that library off my answer, but I didn't.  And for python 2.6 the answer is still no.

Answer (score 6):

Built-in no, as a third party package you can check [blist](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/1.3.4) , here is the doc for [sorteddict](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sorteddict.html).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Python version of the Java TreeMap/TreeSet.

Source code and documentation can be accessed in [this repo](https://github.com/GavinPHR/pytreemap)

You can install with `pip install pytreemap`.
Tested for Python >=3.5

Answer (score 1):

If by build-in you mean provided with a standard python install, the answer is no.

If you mean at the same level of implementation as Python's build-in `dict` then have a look at my C implementation of sorteddict and ordereddict: http://anthon.home.xs4all.nl/Python/ordereddict/