# What is the best data structure to store objects indexed by date?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some objects whicha re associated with dates. I would like to be able to get objects for a given date range, as well as for a single date. 
What is the best data structure in python to do this?

I believe in some languages this would be achieved using a 'Curve'.

Comment: I think you are looking for the Python-equivalent of a Java [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6886294/1639625)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,1)))
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2016-7-1', periods=10, freq='D')
```

For a date range:

```
>>> df[(df['date'] > '2016-7-3') & (df['date'] <= '2016-7-10')]
          0       date
3  0.322654 2016-07-04
4  0.360684 2016-07-05
5  0.298821 2016-07-06
6  0.292097 2016-07-07
7  0.052085 2016-07-08
8  0.620535 2016-07-09
9  0.902022 2016-07-10
```

For a given date:

```
>>> df[df['date'] == '2016-7-3']
          0       date
2  0.191553 2016-07-03
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary would work.  `datetime` objects can be used as dictionary keys, and can be compared against one another in ranges.

Comment: But this does not work if the date you want to look up is between two dates in the dict.

Comment: I assumed the poster was asking for 'tell me if stored date X is between arbitrary dates Y and Z, not 'tell me if arbitrary date X is between stored dates Y and Z'.  But even then it would work, you'd just need to compare each unique pair of dates in the dict against the target date.