# Looping Python dictionaries in entered sequence

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new in Python and while looping through the items of a dictionary structure I discovered that they come up in a different order than the sequence they were entered. That happens in Perl hashes too I think. Is there a simple way to get the items in the "right" order?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key-ordered dict in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319763/key-ordered-dict-in-python)

Comment: @JBernardo, no, that's asking about a *sorted* dict. This is just asking about an *ordered* dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries are inherently unordered; it's what gives them (amortized) O(1) lookups for keys.

In more recent versions of python, there is [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which does preserve insertion order. Or, you could just keep a separate list.

Comment: A separate list of the desired key sequence you mean?

Comment: Note that you can use http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/ in Python 2.4, 2.5, or 2.6.