# How to sort dict by value, when keys are fractions represented by strings?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to sort a dict, where keys are fractions represented by strings and need to be sorted by its numerical values:

i.e.:

```
exp_time = {"2":10, "1/2":5:, "2.5":11, "1/200":9, "15":3, "1/30":6}
```

result should be like this(descending order):

```
15
2.5
2
1/2
1/30
1/200
```

Comment: `dict`'s cannot themselves be sorted, although a list of their keys can.

Comment: You might also be interest in the answers to the question [Key-ordered dict in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1319763/355230).

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> import fractions
>>> exp_time = {"2":10, "1/2":5, "2.5":11, "1/200":9, "15":3, "1/30":6}
>>> sorted(exp_time, key=fractions.Fraction, reverse=True)
['15', '2.5', '2', '1/2', '1/30', '1/200']
```

Comment: +1, I didn't know about the `fractions` module.  I was about to post the same answer but with a hand-rolled implementation of `fractions.Fraction`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning though that a standard dictionary is **unordered**. If all the OP cares about is this final list that's fine, otherwise one should use an ordered dict like `collections.OrderedDict` (Python 2.7+).